# how to call google translate in android application?

Tags: android, multilingual

Could any one please tell me how to call google translate service in my android application.The requirement is ,when i select a particular language the entire content of the android application should change to the selected language.

Comment: [Localization](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html)

Comment: are u creating any translater application in android or do u need any link for google translater. Please say detail on about question

Answer (score 0):

I am going to provide you link that can be help full for your android application in Google translate topic

http://android-er.blogspot.in/2009/10/androidtranslate-using-google-translate.html

http://androiddevelopement.blogspot.in/2012/05/using-google-translate-api-in-android.html

dont forget to vote up if this answer helpful for you